# Looking for tool to migrate Joomla site between servers

Tags: mysql, joomla, migrate

I have to manually migrate a Joomla website to another server (shared hosting). Our current site is still an old joomla version (1.5.9) so I wanted to start from a clean install (1.5.22) and then migrate everything. Are there any components that would help with this?

I learned the DB schema is identical so I could just restore my old database but how to quickly migrate all components/modules/plugins with their settings and the general settings coz I assume those are not stored in the DB? So any component that can export-import all that?

I only have FTP access to both account btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would seriously suggest downloading a copy of the site, creating a local install, doing the upgrade and then uploading the upgraded version to your new server.

Of course the complexity will depend on how frequently content change on your site.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use [Akkeba Backup](http://www.akeebabackup.com/), it is a good and popular extension.
It installs as a component and provides a backup functionality at the Joomla backend (/administrator).

About the update, take a look [here](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/frs/?action=FrsReleaseBrowse&frs_package_id=5848). 
Download Joomla_1.5.9_to_1.5.23-Stable-Patch_Package.zip and extract it into your joomla installation, preferably on your new installation.